# Opening multiple text files into a single .tab file in MapInfo

Tags: mapinfo, text, bathymetry

I am trying to open multiple xyz text files into mapinfo to create a table where i can create a raster image of multibeam bathymetry. 
Is there a script which will open each .txt file and merge them all into a single .tab file. And even create a raster image from this?

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to MapInfo Pro Advanced, you can create a raster from multiple input files. That can be MapInfo tables, LiDAR files or text files.

The dialog below shows the file types that can be selected and processed into a raster grid

[image]